# How to use StringFormat in XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to show a text like this: `10 reviews`

this one works:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Reviews, StringFormat='reviews {0}'}"/>
```

this one works but an error in XAML appears saying `r is unexpected at this position`

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Reviews, StringFormat='{0} reviews'}"/>
```

Comment: Try using `{}` to escape first brace. So it will be `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Reviews, StringFormat='{}{0} reviews'}"/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Reviews, StringFormat='{}{0} reviews'}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also split the text into two `Run` tags:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="{Binding Reviews}" />
    <Run Text=" reviews" />
</TextBlock>
```

That will allow you to localize "reviews" string.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Reviews, StringFormat=\{0\} reviews}"/>
```

It will work :)